# Selenium won't see elements unless I manually resize the window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

One of the desired elements is in the right corner of the page, and selenium will not see it unless I manually resize the window to make the element present. If I do so, everything works fine. Selenium will find the element, click on it, and do what I want it to do. Here is my code in python

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='15_button']")))
num_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='15_button']")
num_list.click()
```

I have tried to resize the window by using

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 1024)
driver.maximize_window()
```

which does make the element visible as the browser starts, but then Selenium gives the error

```
Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1206, 719). Other element would receive the click: <li id="15_input_5" class="selected">...</li>
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means that there is a different `element` covering the `element` you're trying to click. If Selenium tries to click on it the click will actually happen on the element that is covering it, thus it throws this error. You could use `javascript` to click on it, this way it doensn't matter if the `element` is covered or not.

```
num_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='15_button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", num_list)
```

Another tip for you. In your code sample you are doing:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='15_button']")))
num_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='15_button']")
```

The `wait.until()` will return the element once it has decided it is clickable. So you can get rid of the second `find` like so:

```
num_list = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='15_button']")))
```

Comment: You generally want to interact with the site in the way that users would. Using JS to directly click a hidden element is generally not a good practice because the user can't do that. Find out what is hiding the element and dismiss it or you may just need a short wait for the element to appear/disappear.

Comment: The wait.until() tip is a good one but you can go one further and add the .click() to the end of the line and not need to store the element in num_list at all.